# Lodash group By

Tags: lodash

What I need is to group by project, that for each project I am grouped by the stories that are in those projects, and that for each story I show the tasks. When executing the example, we will see that the history 41 that corresponds to the "barney" project is not shown. It groups the stories but does not show the history corresponding to a barney that is not grouped.
This is an example of how it should look

```
 [
  {
    "proyecto": "barney",
    "historia": 42,
    "tarea": [
      "dog",
      "lion",
      "cat"
    ],
    "historia": 41,
    "tarea": [
      "cat"
    ]
  },
  {
    "proyecto": "fred",
    "historia": 35,
    "tarea": [
      "dog",
      "goldfish"
    ]
  }
]
```

```js
group();

function group()
{

var characters = [
  { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 42,  'tarea': 'dog' },
  { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 42,  'tarea': 'lion' },
  { 'proyecto': 'fred',   'historia': 35,  'tarea': 'dog' },
  { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 41,  'tarea': 'cat' },
  { 'proyecto': 'fred',   'historia': 35,  'tarea': 'goldfish' }
];

var result=_.chain(characters).groupBy("proyecto").map(function(v, i) {
  return {
    proyecto: i,
    historia: _.get(_.find(v, 'historia'), 'historia'),
    tarea: _.map(v, 'tarea')
  }
}).value();
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, '  ') + '</pre>';
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your expected result is not valid JS. Please update.

Comment: I think it's fine now, thank you very much

Comment: An object can't have a property name more than once - for example 2 `tarea`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the `lodash` answer here is the **ES6** implementation of this via single [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) just so you have to to compare:

```js
var data = [ { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 42, 'tarea': 'dog' }, { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 42, 'tarea': 'lion' }, { 'proyecto': 'fred', 'historia': 35, 'tarea': 'dog' }, { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 41, 'tarea': 'cat' }, { 'proyecto': 'fred', 'historia': 35, 'tarea': 'goldfish' } ];

const result = data.reduce((r, {proyecto, historia, tarea}) => {
  r[proyecto] = r[proyecto] || {proyecto, historia: [], tarea: []}
  r[proyecto].historia.push(historia)
  r[proyecto].tarea.push(tarea)
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Since you are using `reduce` there is no need for the 2nd `_.map` loop and all can be done in one `"shot"`.

If **ES6** is an issue here is the same implementation with `_.reduce`:

```js
var data = [ { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 42, 'tarea': 'dog' }, { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 42, 'tarea': 'lion' }, { 'proyecto': 'fred', 'historia': 35, 'tarea': 'dog' }, { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 41, 'tarea': 'cat' }, { 'proyecto': 'fred', 'historia': 35, 'tarea': 'goldfish' } ];

const result = _.reduce(data, function(r,c) {
  r[c.proyecto] = r[c.proyecto] || {proyecto: c.proyecto, historia: [], tarea: []}
  r[c.proyecto].tarea.push(c.tarea)
  r[c.proyecto].historia.push(c.historia)
  return r
}, {})

console.log(_.values(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, it is almost what I need, I would miss the story 41 that is not shown

Comment: I updated the answer so you have the `historia` as an array since otherwise you have an invalid object since keys in objects are `unique`. You actual question has also the wrong expectation that you can have multiple `historia` keys in one object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `_.map()` to extract the `historia` (like you do for `tarea`):

```js
var characters = [
  { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 42,  'tarea': 'dog' },
  { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 42,  'tarea': 'lion' },
  { 'proyecto': 'fred',   'historia': 35,  'tarea': 'dog' },
  { 'proyecto': 'barney', 'historia': 41,  'tarea': 'cat' },
  { 'proyecto': 'fred',   'historia': 35,  'tarea': 'goldfish' }
];

var result= _(characters)
  .groupBy("proyecto")
  .map(function(v, i) {
    return {
      proyecto: i,
      historia: _.map(v, 'historia'),
      tarea: _.map(v, 'tarea')
    }
  })
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for answering. Would it be possible to group the story too?
I also need to group the story and each story show their task

Comment: You need to add an example of the expected results.